# Recursive method inside class with initialisation

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am trying to run a simple recursion using classes as follows:

```
class Example:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.depth = 0
        
    def doSomething(self):
        self.depth += 1

        if self.depth < 4:         
            self.depth = self.doSomething(self)
        else:
            return self.depth
        
y = Example()
y.doSomething()
print(y.depth)
```

I am a beginner with classes, so would appreciate feedback on why this doesn't work and how to get around the error I am receiving:

```
TypeError: doSomething() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: There is no need to add `self` to the method, in any case use `self.doSomething()`. Besides that the recursion doesn't always return a value, in any case `return self.depth` is only called when `self.depth` is larger than 3, otherwise the method returns `None` (the default return value). It would be better to add `return self.depth` in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for your response Thymen. I only want the recursion to return 4 at the end. I still can't get it to work even after removing self from the method and calling self.doSomething()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to complicate things. You don't need to return a value.

```py
class Example:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.depth = 0
        
    def doSomething(self):
        self.depth += 1

        if self.depth < 4:         
            self.doSomething()
        
y = Example()
y.doSomething()
print(y.depth)
```

Just call the method again